# Cordova Phonegap Form Input box not working on iOS

Tags: ios, forms, cordova, input

Can't enter text in input form box (keyboard not showing) for iOS. Input box seems non-responsive, as no prompt is shown nor is a keyboard launced(APP). This works fine for Cordova Android (simulator and APP), as well as every standard browser on OSX, Android, and iOS.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; media-src *;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *" />
<title>Input Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input name="auto" type="text" id="idauto" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"><br>
<input name="text" type="text" id="idtext" style="-webkit-user-select: text;"><br>
<input class="newinput" onclick="this.focus();" type="email" id="mix" name="email" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" required="" placeholder="Enter E-mail address">
</form>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*** also tried just 1 input, with same results, so showing that multiple variations act the same.

Cordova: 6.3.1

Emulator: iPhone-SE, 10.1 simulator (verified same behavior in actual iOS APP through iTunes Connect, so sticking with simulator to try to fix).

My Cordova config.xml preferences are:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />

<!-- iOS only preferences -->
<preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="My Browser" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local"/>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"/>
<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>
<preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>
<preference name="MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" value="false"/>
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 My Browser" />
<preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>
<preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>
<preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true"/>
<preference name="SuppressesLongPressGesture" value="true" />
<preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="true" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="white"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="fast" />
```

Cordova plugins (installed because this example is a snippet from a much larger project).

```
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.1.0 "Whitelist"
```

Comment: <script src="cordova.js"></script> should be in head

Comment: @Eric Thanks, but that did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suppresses3DTouchGesture disables onclick handlers, which effectively disables input boxes.

To fix, delete the preference or set it to "false"

```
<preference name="Suppresses3DTouchGesture" value="false" />
```